# Is there a way in Microsoft Excel to give specific bins different bin widths when making a histogram plot?

Tags: excel

I am trying to give specific bins on my histogram plot different bin widths. Is there a way to say I want bin 1 to have a width 1-10 and bin 20 to have a width of 300-1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel builtin histogram tool only allows equal bin-width. We must create instead a ["variable width column chart"](https://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/) as explained by Jon Peltier. This can be a tedious and error-prone process if you've got a lot of bins.
[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYUcZO23jz8) for Excel 2016. The main steps are as followed:

1. Create a cascade table:

[image: Input table]

should turn into:

[image: Cascade table]

Note: dummy + Label columns aren't required, but helps with labeling

2. generates an stacked area chart (a type of Area chart)

[image: stacked area chart]

3. Then *change the Primary Axis's category to Time-Scale* to straighten the areas into bars. As explained by Jon Peltier, this is because:

> This is somewhat misleading, as Excel time-scale axes only consider
> dates and ignore times.

[image: straightened columns]